# I can not get the items of a listview

Tags: android

I have two textview in my hola.xml file, I want to show is the first (0). thanks

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNMAT1);
String foo = ((TextView)((ViewGroup) arg1).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
t.setText(foo);
```

Comment: Change infoM.getItemAtPosition(posicion) to posicion

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to get the text of the selected item

Comment: what I get as a result is "android.database.sqlite.SqliteCursor@43e4de30".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> infoM, View arg1, int posicion, long _id)
    {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNMAT1);
        String foo = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();

        t.setText(foo);
    }
```

the first `param` is the object that holds the `Adapter` info (`Spinner`, `ListView`, etc...) and the second `param` is the `View` which was clicked (here a `TextView`). So get the text which is in that `TextView`.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: Yes! This should work, else the OPs code is wrong somewhere, but we cannot smell it. If this does not work, OP need to give the XML of `R.layout.hola` aswell as `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: The method getText() is undefined for the type View. I have this error

Comment: sorry, I'm new at this. Add it to the question. Thanks for responding

Comment: What is in `hola.xml`? The problem is I assumed it was just a `TextView` but you are getting exception trying to cast `LinearLayout` to a `TextView`

Comment: tengo definido un linerLayout y dos textviews

Comment: I have defined a linerLayout and two textviews

Comment: Well, depending on which `TextView` you are looking for you can modify it to `arg1.getChildAt(index)`. And please rename `arg1` to something meaningful

Comment: Thank you!. Now it works perfect with this modification. I have two textview in my hola.xml file, I want to show is the first (0). thanks